# What permission is needed to set Database read-only?

Tags: sql-server, permissions

I am dbowner of a database which I want to set read-only. (through sql management studio). When I try that I get a permission error (297)

Which role is needed to perform that action?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Form Query Analyzer or Management Studio, you can issue the following command:

```
ALTER DATABASE database-name SET READ_ONLY
```

As mentioned [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522682.aspx), you need the alter database rights and you must set the database to single mode.

> Changing the state of a database or filegroup to READ_ONLY or
>   READ_WRITE requires exclusive access to the database.

```
USE master;
GO
ALTER DATABASE AdventureWorks2012
SET SINGLE_USER
WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
GO
ALTER DATABASE AdventureWorks2012
SET READ_ONLY;
GO
ALTER DATABASE AdventureWorks2012
SET MULTI_USER;
GO
```

Answer (score -1):

There is a system stored procedure. You can also use this for this task.

```
> Syntax: sp_dboption [ [ @dbname = ] 'database' ] 
>     [ , [ @optname = ] 'option_name' ] 
>     [ , [ @optvalue = ] 'value' ]  [;]
```

Example:

```
 EXEC SP_DBOPTION   -- To check Settable option

 EXEC SP_DBOPTION 'MyDatabase' -- Return the following option that are
 set.

 EXEC SP_DBOPTION 'MyDatabase','READ ONLY' --- Set the Read Only to the db

 EXEC SP_DBOPTION 'MyDatabase','READ ONLY','FALSE' --- Change the
 current setting of the option
```

Comment: [No](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187310%28v=SQL.105%29.aspx). `"This feature will be removed in the next version of Microsoft SQL Server. Do not use this feature in new development work, and modify applications that currently use this feature as soon as possible. Use ALTER DATABASE instead."`